# Is there any way to convery curl command into php curl

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am a Server admin, and i dont have any knowledge of PHP.

Can anyone please help me to convert this following curl command into php curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"SystemsTraceAuditNumber":"455690","RetrievalReferenceNumber":"405060908072","AcquiringBin":"409999","AcquirerCountryCode":"101","PrimaryAccountNumber":"4895070000008881"}'
-v --ciphers RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5 https://sandbox.visa.com/rsrv_vpp/v1/acnl -u 72cdcdd2-9ccd-4adc-8827-0324324523423414a:f42342317-b62340-42343e-8234-e2342342341357b0
--cacert ./SMCAroot.crt --cert /home/sourcecode/sandbox_cert.pem -k
```

I have tried converting the code but messed up everything, i am getting http 500 response which using php.

but when i am executing the curl command on linux shell, its working fine

following is the code which i converted in php

```
<?php
$data = array(
   'SystemsTraceAuditNumber' => '455690',
   'RetrievalReferenceNumber' => '405060908072',
   'AcquiringBin' => '409999',
   'AcquirerCountryCode' => '101',
   'PrimaryAccountNumber' => '4895070000008881',
);
//echo $data;
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$handle=curl_init('https://sandbox.visa.com/rsrv_vpp/v1/acnl');

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'sandbox_cert.pem');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json')
);
$handle;

$content = curl_exec($handle);

if(!curl_errno($handle))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($handle);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($info);
    echo "</pre>";

    //echo '<br/> Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
}
else
{
    'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);
}
$content;

?>
```

Comment: The option `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'sandbox_cert.pem');` That should have the same path I believe: `/home/sourcecode/sandbox_cert.pem`, so that it reads: `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/home/sourcecode/sandbox_cert.pem');

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to set them up like so:

```
$defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5',
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT => '/home/sourcecode/sandbox_cert.pem',
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandbox.visa.com/rsrv_vpp/v1/acnl',
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json')
);

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($handle, ($options + $defaults));
if( ! $content = curl_exec($handle)){
    trigger_error(curl_error($handle));
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```